# OPEN AN ACTIVITY FOR THE FIRST TIME STARTED APP ON THE SMARTPHONE

Tags: android

Good evening i will start one activity main layout for the first time app started on a smartphone, how can i do?
This is my main activity... when my apo start you can see my activity_main to chose the notifications to recive from firebase and when i set up the notifications the app redirect you to another activity_mainweb when i put a webview, i want to see only for the first time the first activity_main layout

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // If a notification message is tapped, any data accompanying the notification
    // message is available in the intent extras. In this sample the launcher
    // intent is fired when the notification is tapped, so any accompanying data would
    // be handled here. If you want a different intent fired, set the click_action
    // field of the notification message to the desired intent. The launcher intent
    // is used when no click_action is specified.
    //
    // Handle possible data accompanying notification message.
    // [START handle_data_extras]
    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
            Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        }
    }
    // [END handle_data_extras]

    Button subscribeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton0);
    subscribeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // [START subscribe_topics]
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("INTERIORDESIGN150H");
            // [END subscribe_topics]

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Button subscribeButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton1);
    subscribeButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // [START subscribe_topics]
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("INTERIORDESIGN300H");
            // [END subscribe_topics]

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });




    Button subscribeButton2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton2);
    subscribeButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // [START subscribe_topics]
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("GARDENDESIGN150H");
            // [END subscribe_topics]

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



    Button subscribeButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton3);
    subscribeButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // [START subscribe_topics]
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("GARDENDESIGN300H");
            // [END subscribe_topics]

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });




    Button subscribeButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton4);
    subscribeButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // [START subscribe_topics]
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("VISUALDESIGN150H");
            // [END subscribe_topics]

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });




    Button subscribeButton5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton5);
    subscribeButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // [START subscribe_topics]
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("PRODUCTDESIGN150H");
            // [END subscribe_topics]

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



    Button subscribeButton6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton6);
    subscribeButton6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // [START subscribe_topics]
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("MOTIONDESIGN150H");
            // [END subscribe_topics]

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



    Button subscribeButton7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton7);
    subscribeButton7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // [START subscribe_topics]
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("GRAPHICDESIGN150H");
            // [END subscribe_topics]

            // Log and toast
            String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
            Log.d(TAG, msg);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    Button Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton0);

    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityweb.class));
        }
    });
    Button Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton1);

    Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityweb.class));
        }
    });
    Button Button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton2);

    Button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityweb.class));
        }
    });
    Button Button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton3);

    Button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityweb.class));
        }
    });
    Button Button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton4);

    Button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityweb.class));
        }
    });
    Button Button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton5);

    Button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityweb.class));
        }
    });
    Button Button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton6);

    Button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityweb.class));
        }
    });
    Button Button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subscribeButton7);

    Button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivityweb.class));
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: why? it is a simple question, i have to open one of my layout activities only when the app start for the first time on the smartphone.

Comment: why? because the question looks like it was processed by a bad translation app and does not make sense.

Comment: I don't think. because i write what i need and i have received a response.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SharedPrefs to track whether it's the first launch and redirect to the other layout if it is

```
private static final String KEY_HAS_BEEN_LAUNCHED_BEFORE = "KEY_HAS_BEEN_LAUNCHED";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    boolean hasBeenLaunchedBefore = prefs.getBoolean(KEY_HAS_BEEN_LAUNCHED_BEFORE , false);
    setContentView(hasBeenLaunchedBefore ? R.layout.normal_layout 
                                         : R.layout.first_launch_layout);
    if (!hasBeenLaunchedBefore) {
        //after the first launch, record that it's been seen
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_HAS_BEEN_LAUNCHED_BEFORE , true);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check my question now?

Comment: He wrote the entire code snippet for you, what do you want more ? Just copy and paste it.

Comment: it is not function